# Can't See the Widgets page in Magento Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, widgets

new to Magento, so apologies if I am missing required information.. please let me know if so and I will elaborate/add more info.

I have inherited a project involving Magento for a large store (v 1.9.0.1). There has been no handover and no line of communication with the previous developer.

I am slowly working things out and teaching myself Magento, however I have just come across an issue where the Widgets page under CMS in the back end is simply blank with no options.

Further more, if I look in a static block that has a widget in and double clikc on it in the editor, I get the widget selection block, but the widget option block is missing with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setWidgetType() on a non-object in <server>/app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php on line 62
```

I have cross referenced this php file with one from a vanilla install (where widgets work) and it is identical.

Finally, the widget renders fine on the live site?

Has anyone seen this before?

Once again, sorry if there is not enough information here, please let me know what else I should post.

Thanks a lot for anyone taking the time to respond.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get an answer to this, however I have resolved the issue myself, So I am posting it on here to help anyone else who comes across this.

After some file comparison with a vanilla install, I found that the following files:

Instance.php
Options.php

.. from the location:

app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/

.. were missing. Simply uploading these from a working installation of Magento fixed the problem immediately.

I realise this is probably why there was no answer - it is not going to be a common problem, however I am posting this just to point anyone in the right direction in case they happen to have the same issue.